# String Array getters and for loops

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
static String[] name = {"Alberts, Nancy", "Bly, Joshua", "Cox, Alex", 
                        "Hood, Ben", "Kelly, Amber", "Lizarde, Adriana", 
                        "Olson, Ashely," + "Perez, Julisa", "Perez, Maria",
                        "Rhodes, Jonathan"};
```

I need to write a

```
public static String getName(String[] array) {
    ?
}
```

but idk what to put inside in order to get it to print in the main class

Comment: What do you mean print in the main class?

Comment: What is getName supposed to return? A specific string from the array?

Comment: Not nearly enough information here about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you asking [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409784/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

```
static String[] name = {"Alberts, Nancy", "Bly, Joshua", "Cox, Alex", 
        "Hood, Ben", "Kelly, Amber", "Lizarde, Adriana", 
        "Olson, Ashely," + "Perez, Julisa", "Perez, Maria",
"Rhodes, Jonathan"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String s: name) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
public static String[] getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Is this what you're trying to do?